# Сниппеты Android, для отправки сообщений и вызовов во все популярные мессенджеры (Viber, Whatsapp, Facebook Messenger)

Tags: android, messenger, viber, whatsapp

Собственно предлагаю собрать тут все скрипты чтоб по сайтам не лазить.

Пока нашел скрипт для Viber

```
String sphone = "9000000000";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(sphone));
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        intent.setClassName("com.viber.voip", "com.viber.voip.WelcomeActivity");
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        AppContext.getAppContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Скрипт открывает viber по номеру и предлагает совершить вызов или отправить сообщение.

Нужны такие же штуки для:
Контакта
Фэйсбука
Facebook Messenger
WhatsApp
Теллеграмм
WeChat 
...

Comment: Ваш пример не учитывает того, что приложения может и не быть на девайсе. В этом случае приложение с этим кодом упадёт. Также, для некоторых соц сетей некоторые действия можно делать чрез браузер. Т.е. сформировать ссылку коя откроет страницу с нужным действием.

Comment: Дык, ответ сам себя не напишет)

Comment: Это можно назвать сниппетами, но не скриптами. Скрипты это из другой области (web в основном)

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp позволяет отправить письмо только если номер есть в контактах

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "9211889055");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
```

В Facebook messenger я так понял что нужно знать id пользователя в facebook (типа числа Long). Но этот id можно узнать через API или предложить пользователям выкавыривать их из своих страниц.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/");
uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri,100001899606015L);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Приложения Контакта и FB для андройд я так понял не позволяют открыть контакт адресата без задействования своего API.

**Поправьте меня если я не прав...**